# Calculate start index and end index in list

Tags: java

Some one please help me on the below query in java,

I want to calculate start index and end index from Array List in Java, is there any way how to do this... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Start index is always 0 and end index will be one less than the number of element you insert

Comment: Please read the basics of JAVA there are tons of resources.

Answer (score 0):

The `beginning index` is always `0`. The `last index` will be `size of the list minus 1`. In code, it will be something like,

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");

        int beginIndex = 0; // Always the begin index is zero
        int lastIndex = list.size() - 1; // Size of list minus 1

        System.out.println("Begin Index - " + beginIndex);
        System.out.println("Last Index - " + lastIndex);
    }
}
```